# How can I speed up build of c++ project using OpenCV on WSL2?

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I have a c++ project that uses the OpenCV library. It takes a long time to build when I run `make`. How can I speed up the build time?

I did install OpenCV with GPU support and thought this might be the bottleneck (since it may be compiling for different GPU architectures?), so I tried using `cmake -D WITH_CUDA=OFF ..` to build my project. Unfortunately, this didn't do the trick... Any tips?

Note: I'm fine disabling the GPU if it speeds up compile time significantly.

This is what my CMakeLists.txt file looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(Cruisin VERSION 1.0)
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package (Threads)

include_directories(include)
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

file(GLOB SOURCES src/*.cpp app/main.cpp)

add_executable(main ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries( main ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT} ) # Add threading lib
target_link_libraries( main ${OpenCV_LIBS} )

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
```

Other Details:

- Compiler: gcc
- OS: virtual Ubuntu 20.04 (WSL2 on Windows 10)
- Project structure: there's one main cpp file in `ROOT/app/`, 2 source files in `ROOT/src/` with 2 corresponding headers in `ROOT/include/`
- OpenCV and my project files are located on the regular Windows file system (accessed through `/mnt/` directory), but CUDA and Make/CMake are in the virtual WSL

## Edit: Solution

The issue seemed to be WSL being very slow with any I/O being done in the windows filesystem. In my case, I was using OpenCV installed somewhere in `mnt/` (Windows filesystem). I rebuilt OpenCV in WSL somewhere in `/`, and moved my project there as well and it is so much faster.

Comment: Are we talking 10+ minutes or hours or what? I have not noticed typical projects using OpenCV to take an unusually long time to build on a modern cpu with 6 or more cores.

Comment: We are talking 10+ minutes. With that said, there isn't much going on in this cpp project yet (few files, not many lines), however I was able to compile a different OpenCV project with comparable size in 1-2 minutes... I'm not sure why this project is taking so much longer

Comment: please post a log of the build process. we need to see what all is being built, and if that is necessary.

Comment: `CMakeLists.txt` looks good and is similar to many other scripts on this topic. Specifics could be in your source files, platform, compiler.. but you describe none of them. So, what do you want from us with that information?

Comment: Well, you have several lines from CMake/Make which performs building and linking of your source files. Which line among those takes the **most amount of time**? How long is this amount? Since you work with WSL2, it has different access time for files inside guest filesystem (Ubuntu 20.04 in your case) and outside it. So, where your source and build directory is located, **inside** Ubuntu or **outside** it?

Comment: Thank you Tsyvarev, your comment led me to the solution. The issue was how I had OpenCV and my project in the windows filesystem instead of somewhere in `/`.

Answer (score 4):

Are you rebuilding OpenCV library each time you build your project? This can happen unintentionally in some cases if you add the library as an external project. OpenCV should only be built once as a target and then linked in to your executable target with `target_link_libraries`.

Also you can set the `-j` flag for number of threads, see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/manual/cmake.1.html#build-tool-mode.

It is difficult to say more without seeing your CMakeLists.txt file.

Comment: I've already been using the -j flag, but thanks for the suggestion. I have just updated my question with the CMakeList.txt file; Is there anything out of the ordinary there?

Comment: Perhaps a silly question but is `src/*.cpp`, your src files only and does not contain any external source files, because they will all be built.

Comment: Yep, `src/*.cpp` are only my source files

Answer (score 0):

use make -j x
x = number of cores
example:

```
make -j 8
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Luis, I've already been using the -j flag however

Answer (score -2):

Try to use [Meson Build System](https://mesonbuild.com) and `ninja`.

Comment: we don't know yet whether cmake is causing the problem. OP hasn't given any details to determine that. in any case it's premature to recommend switching build systems.